# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'userX'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to creating a login page when I tried to log in it give me this error.

No clue how to fix it.

Any ideas?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistroConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = " select count(*) from NewLogins where username = '" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "' and Password = '" + TextBoxPassword.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from NewLogins where username'" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
            string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            conn.Close();
            if (password == TextBoxPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxUsername.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password is not correct");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Username is not correct");
        }

    }
```

This is the error that I got:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'userX'

On this line string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");

Comment: You haven't specified what error you got.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'userX'

Comment: `where username=` . The query is missing the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from NewLogins where username='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
```

"=" operator is added as mentioned by @Igor Tandetnik